# Cannot pass array of string to function

Tags: node.js, typescript, lodash, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this function:

```
function proc(unames: Array<string>){}
```

I try to pass it this:

```
  import _ = require('lodash');

  const usernames = _.flattenDeep([unames]).filter(function (item, index, arr) {
     return item && arr.indexOf(item) === index;
  });

  const recipient = 'foobarbaz';
  proc(usernames.concat(recipient));
```

I get this error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to mitigate this?

I tried this, and I get an even longer and crazier error:

```
function proc(unames: Array<string | ReadonlyArray<string>>){}
```

however, this made the error go away:

```
function proc(unames: Array<string | ReadonlyArray<any>>){}
```

not really sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The warning seems to be referring to the use of [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) rather than `proc()`.

When called on an `Array`, such as `usernames`, TypeScript is validating that the arguments given to `.concat()` are also `Array`s.

To resolve the warning, you have a few options:

- Since you're using Lodash, its own [`_.concat()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#concat) allows for appending individual values, and TypeScript's validation should be aware of that:

  ```
  const recipient = 'foobarbaz';
  proc(_.concat(usernames, recipient));
  ```
- Define `recipient` as an `Array` or wrap it when calling `.concat()`:

  ```
  const recipient = [ 'foobarbaz' ];
  proc(usernames.concat(recipient));
  ```

  ```
  const recipient = 'foobarbaz';
  proc(usernames.concat( [recipient] ));
  ```
- You may also be able to configure TypeScript to validate for a later version of ECMAScript. Between [5.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-15.4.4.4) and [2015 (6th edition)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.concat) of the standard, the behavior of the built-in `.concat()` was changed to support individual values (by detecting *spreadable*).

  For now, TypeScript is validating `.concat()` for 5.1 or older.

Comment: @AlexanderMills Sorry. Correction: The method does support individual values now (starting with ECMAScript 2015, or the 6th edition), however TypeScript is still only considering it valid when the argument is an Array.

Comment: yeah, that's weird, seems like `[].concat('foo')` has been supported by JS for awhile

Comment: @AlexanderMills That may be configurable, perhaps related to the target for build output, and array-only is just the default for highest compatibility.